# PHP code does not recognize some values

Tags: php, angularjs

**EDIT:** Thank you all for the very quick answers! I have been at this for a while, trying to figure out why $id was being recognized and why the strings weren't. I feel a bit silly now seeing the obvious answer but I'm relieved to have it working.

I apologize if this has been answered before, I've looked for hours and could not find something similar to help me figure this out.

I am trying to update a row in my database of devices with new information. Problem is, the php file only recognizes `$data->devID;` and nothing else.

If I have something like
`$sql = "UPDATE devices SET devName = 'static test string', description = 'static test string' WHERE devID = $id";` 
the entry with the correct ID will update in my database table just fine.

If I try 
`$sql = "UPDATE devices SET devName = $name, description = $desc WHERE devID = $id";` 
it does not work.

Where am I going wrong?

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="info in deviceInfo">
    <form class="deviceInfo">
        <h2>Device ID: {{info.devID}}</h2>
        <p>Device Name:</p>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="info.devName">
        <p>Device Description:</p>
        <textarea data-ng-model="info.description"></textarea>
        <p>Device Available: {{info.isAvailable}}</p>
        <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update" data-ng-click="updateInfo(info.devID, info.devName, info.description)">
    </form>
</div>
```

updateDeviceInfo.php:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

include('config.php');

$id = $data->devID; 
$name = $data->devName;
$desc = $data->description;

$sql = "UPDATE devices SET devName = $name, description = $desc WHERE devID = $id";

$qry = $conn->query($sql);

$data = $qry;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM devices";

$qry = $conn->query($sql);

$data = array();

if($qry->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $qry->fetch_object()){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}else {
    $data[] = null;
}

$conn->close();

echo json_encode($data);
```

controller.js:

```
$scope.updateInfo = function($paramID, $paramName, $paramDesc){

    console.log($paramID);
    console.log($paramName);
    console.log($paramDesc);

    $scope.dataOneTest = {
            devID: $paramID,
            devName: $paramName,
            description: $paramDesc

        };

    console.log($scope.dataOneTest.devID);

    $http.post('./js/updateDeviceInfo.php', {'devID': $paramID, 'devName': $paramName, 'description': $paramDesc})
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.results = data;
        })
        .error(function(err){
            $log.error(err);
        })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** You are almost certainly performing [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) on yourself *both* by inserting variables directly into a query *and* by failing to use proper quotation marks around them.

You need to use prepared statements, rather than concatenating variables directly into your query. If, for example, `$data->devName` contained something nefarious like `NULL --`, that would toast your entire table. And that's a very mild example of how badly things could go. Prepared statements would render that example (and pretty much all other examples) harmless.

## Short-Term Fix

As a short-term fix, put quotation marks in the query and escape your data, like this:

```
$id = your_database_escape_function($data->devID); 
$name = your_database_escape_function($data->devName);
$desc = your_database_escape_function($data->description);

$sql = "UPDATE devices SET devName = '$name', description = '$desc' WHERE devID = $id";
```

substituting your database's corresponding escaping function for `your_database_escape_function()`. For example, use `$conn->real_escape_string()` if `$conn` is a `MySQLi` object. See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

## The Real Fix

Here's how you *really* do it correctly, and the solution you should implement ASAP. That is, do this before you go any further if at all possible. **Use prepared statements.**

Read [this entire Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/2057919) and [this cheat sheet from OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Use_Prepared_Statements) (no affiliation) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, I will read all of those to remind myself of the proper way to do things. I'm coming back to php from a very long break and I've forgotten everything almost.

Answer (score 1):

change this becuase description and devName which are string should be quoted

$sql = "UPDATE devices SET devName = $name, description = $desc WHERE devID = $id";

to

$sql = "UPDATE devices SET devName = '".$name."', description = '".$desc."' WHERE devID = $id";

Answer (score 1):

Try this, $sql = "UPDATE devices SET devName = '$name', description = '$desc' WHERE devID = $id";

As title and description are string it requires single quote wrapping inside double quotes.